# Repeatable animation with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I'm using a custom directive to trigger an animation on an element when a specified field is blank on the page.  As of now when a user clicks the button with my custom directive the animation will work, once.  Clicking the button again will not fire the animation and I'm not sure why.  I have attempted to use .then() with the $animate service however no luck.

Thanks in advance for any/all assistance.

```js
(function () {

    'use strict'

    ice.directive('cfWobbler', ['$animate', '$parse', cfWobbler])

    function cfWobbler($animate, $parse) {
        var ret = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        }

        return ret;

        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var el = document.getElementById('division-holder');
            var fn = $parse(attrs['cfWobbler']);
            elem.on('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (fn(scope) === '') {
                        $animate.removeClass(el, 'bounceInDown');
                        debugger;
                        $animate.addClass(el, 'wobbler', function () {
                            $animate.removeClass(el, 'wobbler')
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

I got it working however I have an error in my console.  I know I've committed a big "No No" as far as Angular but I am not sure how else to do it.

Here is the error in my console.

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Here's my working code.

```js
(function () {

    'use strict'

    ice.directive('cfWobbler', ['$animate', '$parse', cfWobbler])

    function cfWobbler($animate, $parse) {
        var ret = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        }

        return ret;

        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var el = document.getElementById('division-holder');
            var fn = $parse(attrs['cfWobbler']);
            elem.on('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (fn(scope) === '') {
                        debugger;
                        $animate.removeClass(el, 'bounceInDown');
                        $animate.removeClass(el, 'wobbler');
                        scope.$apply();
                        $animate.addClass(el, 'wobbler');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Check out $animateCss.  You can have multiple animations running, and it is then-able.  ```var animation = $animateCss(el, {removeClass: 'bounceInDown', addClass: 'wobbler'}); animation.start().done(function(){ //After animation is done in here });```

Comment: I tried using $animateCss however that took me a step backwards (I probably am using it wrong).  The element will no longer wobble on a click or any following clicks of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, sans error(s) in the console.

```js
(function () {

    'use strict'

    ice.directive('cfWobbler', ['$animate', '$parse', cfWobbler])

    function cfWobbler($animate, $parse) {
        var ret = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        }

        return ret;

        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var el = document.getElementById('division-holder');
            var fn = $parse(attrs['cfWobbler']);
            elem.on('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    $animate.removeClass(el, 'bounceInDown');
                    $animate.removeClass(el, 'wobbler');
                });
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (fn(scope) === '') {
                        $animate.addClass(el, 'wobbler');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```